# Dynamically select columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a question regarding the creation of a script to dynamically select columns for a `select` statement. Here is my scenario:

I have some tables that have columns that are called "text1-n", "value1-n", "checkbox1-n" etc. I want to check whether these columns have values stored  and if so what data is stored. The Problem is that different tables have a different number of columns and not all tables have all of these columns.

So Table1 may have "text1", "text2", "value1", "value2",... while Table2 has only "text1-5".

To get the column names I use this statement:

```sql
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max) = '...';

SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name
    AND (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'text%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'combobox%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'date%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'checkbox%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'value%');
```

The goal is to get a dynamically created statemant like

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    Combobox1
   ,Combobox2
   ,Combobox3
   ,Combobox4
   ,Date1
   ,Date2
   ,Text1
   ,Text2
FROM ...
```

I've found a similar thread, but I don't understand the DynamicSQL part so that I can adopt it to my needs.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: This sounds like you are breaking all sorts of normalisation rules. Why not fix your design? Clearly going down a dynamic SQL path is the wrong choice here as you don't know what you're doing with it (which makes it *very* dangerous).

Comment: Why don't you use for example DB Forge Search ? There is a lot of build in functions that you can search for value or table parameter etc in entire database. This is waste of time to try do something like you want.

Comment: @Adamszsz Using a seperate tool is not possible as we do not have always the right to install tools on the client database server. So I need a script to get the information out of the system.

Comment: @Larnu not sure why it breaks rules of normalisation. I can't change the design.

Comment: Well, to start with, `text1`, and `text2` should be 2 rows, in a column called `text`, not 2 columns. `Combobox1`,`Combobox2`,`Combobox3`, and `Combobox4` should be 4 rows, in a column called `Combobox`. Most likely you should have multiple tables here. Or you need to name your columns *way* better. But, again, creating a design that *requires* dynamic SQL is most certainly a design flaw. Fix the design, and the problem doesn't exist. With respect, you clearly aren't familiar with Dynamic SQL, so using a design that mandates it is so a *bad* idea. Use a "normal" approach.

Comment: These columns are fields that rely to one dataset in the specific table. Maybe I was not specific enough at the begining but there are of course more columns for each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max) 
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME varchar(max)      
Declare cur22 Cursor FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY  FOR 

SELECT
    Table_Name , COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'text%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'combobox%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'date%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'checkbox%'
        OR COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'value%');
        
    OPEN cur22
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur22
    INTO @table_name , @COLUMN_NAME

        while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        begin
            
            EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' Where LEN(' + @COLUMN_NAME + ') > 0')

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur22
    INTO  @table_name , @COLUMN_NAME
        end
Close cur22
Deallocate cur22
```

Answer (score 0):

A more lowtech solution would be to make a view per table that have all columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT
null as Combobox1
,Combobox2
,Combobox3
,null as Combobox4
,null as Date1
,null as Date2
,Text1
,Text2
FROM <tablename>
```

It may be a little annoying to maintain, but you will get code that is a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this thread... I could manage to create the desired statement/Script.

```sql
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max) = 'par_companygroup2';
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max);

SET @SQL =
'SELECT DISTINCT ' + (SELECT
        p.*
    FROM (SELECT
            STUFF((SELECT
                    +',' +
                    Column_name
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @table_name
                AND (
                Column_name LIKE 'text%'
                OR Column_name LIKE 'combobox%'
                OR Column_name LIKE 'date%'
                OR Column_name LIKE 'checkbox%'
                OR Column_name LIKE 'value%'
                )
                ORDER BY 1 ASC
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)
            .value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Column_name) p)
+ ' FROM ' + @table_name

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```