# Get records with column name like

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 10 %year% 
FROM Table1
```

How to select records with like column in SQL Server?

Basically I want to see rows of all column names that contain "year" within it.

well normally we do like select top 10 column1,column2... so on
but i have 20+ column in tables with some similarity between them & have different tables with different similarities so i really can't write this much column for select.. So is there way to do like with same similarity in column i can select all.

Comment: This sounds like at [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: `Select top 10 * from Table1 where Column1 like '%keyword%'`

Comment: You can keep adding `or column2 like...` etc. But you probably want is to use dynamic SQL to generate (and execute) your query, especially if you could have columns names unknown at the query time. I suggest sticking to a long `OR` statement before getting into dynamic SQL though.

Comment: you can run: `select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id('Table1') and name like '%year%'` and then copy those names into a query. This can also be done dynamically, but it's usually good to know how to walk before joining the new space mission

Comment: @FAB I knew that but count of column that is like name is more than 20 and there are more tables with different similarly on column name so I really can't write every column name for different tables

Comment: @siggemannen looks more logical answer thanks..

Comment: @thoma nope I don't think

Comment: *"nope I don't think"* you might want to rephrase that... I am sure you have *some* thoughts. I'd like to hope you thought about the problem here before you posted it too as well; if you that's not exactly an example of showing research effort (before posting the question), which is something you should (read "need to") be doing before asking.

Comment: @ThomA the question has been edited sir thanks for information.. threre is no where to answer about this question i mean i unable to find

Comment: So, what's wrong with `SELECT CalendarYear, FinancialYear, ArbitraryYear FROM dbo.YourTable;`? Why are you unable to write the query you need?

Comment: nothing wrong sir if theres like 3 there will be load if it will be 20 i asked for short way doing that sir...

Comment: So write the 20 columns... Though, if you have 20 year columns, it sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/); specifically that you have a denormalised design.

Comment: @Christopher - this is just one example from Stackoverflow, but easy to find numerous other examples. Is a lot faster to run a google search yourself than posting a question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633178/dynamically-select-columns-in-sql

Comment: Long story short, there is no "short" way of querying from multiple columns. And since you're not familiar enough with writing actual SQL code, I suggest staying away from dynamic sql and take Thom's advice on writing 20 columns.

Comment: There are short ways of getting all the columns, from the table, @Christopher, such as dragging the columns from the object explorer, or installing a tool that allows you to "[Tab] out" the `*` of `SELECT *`. As for getting only the year columns, as I noted, if you have 20+ "year columns" you must certainly have a denormalisation issue, so your aim should be to fix the design, then your query likely is as simple as `SELECT YearType, YearValue FROM...`

Comment: @thoma thanks for information sir am understanding..

Comment: Your database design is wrong. And regarding _so i really can't write this much column for select_... that is just being lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this via dynamic SQL

```sql
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50) = 'Table1';
    DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(50) = 'Year';
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);

    SELECT
    @sql = 'SELECT '+ 
        (
            SELECT  STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(name),',') 
            FROM    sys.columns 
            WHERE   object_id = object_id(@TableName) 
            AND name LIKE '%'+@ColumnName+'%'
        ) +
        ' FROM ' + @TableName 

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: *Careful*; if the column's name requires delimit identifying, this will fail. Also, this is wide open to injection with the variable `@TableName`.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rRFSCkKa) demonstrating flaws.